# My response is not getting updated from the endpoint after saving a record

Tags: angular

I am calling a POST method to save a record and after getting a successful response, I am calling the GET endpoint to display the records. But the issue is, my response is not getting updated as soon as I am saving the record. I have tried the setTimeOut, and it is taking minimum 800 ms to update the response.

This is my save function:

```
  addpaymentMethod() {
    this.billingService.savePaymentMethod(this.paymentMethodData).subscribe((response: any) => {
      if (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.dialogRef.close(response.result);
      }
    },
      (error: any) => {
        this.dialogRef.close('error');
      })
  }
```

This is the function which loads the Get response.

```
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res) {
        console.log('load');
        this.loadPaymentMethods();
        this.openMsgDialog('Payment method added successfully!', 'success');
      }

  loadPaymentMethods() {
    var reqParams = "customerId=" + (this.isUnitDetails ? this.currentItem.id : this.selectedVacantUnitDetails.id);

    this.tenantFormsBillingService.getPaymentMethods(reqParams).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.datasource.data = res.data;

    })
  }
```

Comment: As far as I saw do you call "getPaymentMethods" at good time,  are you triggering dialog close when do you have the response from save, which is good. Is somebody triggering dialog close earlier?

Comment: @ZsoltBalint, I am calling "loadPaymentMethods" after closing the dialog and only after getting the successful response from the POST endpoint.

Comment: quick and dirty: move `this.openMsgDialog` after `this.datasource.data = res.data;`, i.e. when the request is actually finished, now it seems it runs before (because http/loadPaymentMethods is async)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a sync problem between modal open and data source set time.

You could try with this, to fix the sync problem:

```js
loadPaymentMethods(callback: Function) {
  const reqParams = "customerId=" + (this.isUnitDetails ? this.currentItem.id : this.selectedVacantUnitDetails.id);

  this.tenantFormsBillingService.getPaymentMethods(reqParams).subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
    this.datasource.data = res.data;
    callback();
  });
}

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  if (res) {
    console.log('load');
    this.loadPaymentMethods(() => {
      this.openMsgDialog('Payment method added successfully!', 'success');
    });
  }
});
```